# how to load from access database to datagridview depends on combobox selection

Tags: c#, datagrid

i am getting this error

> System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [Server].'

Depends on the combobox slection i want to load data from access database
[Server data from database that depends on that server field

[i want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AhgW.png) i want to load data in datagrid][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK41s.png)

Help me to load data from access database to datagrid depends on the combobox

```
      namespace CatiaLicenseUsageReport
      {
        public partial class FrmCatiaLicenseUsageReport : Form
{
    FileIO objFileIO ;
    Utilities objUtilities ;
    DBIO objDBIO ;

    private string logfilepath = "";
    private string DBPath = "";

    public FrmCatiaLicenseUsageReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
       
    }
             }

        private void cmbServer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataView dv = new DataView(objDBIO.ImportLicenseUsageDataFromDB(DBPath));
       dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Server LIKE '%{0}%'", cmbServer.SelectedItem.ToString());
        LicenseAllctnGridView.DataSource = dv;
    }


      //Database connection code
        namespace CatiaLicenseUsageReport.IO
       {
        public class DBIO
       {
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>


    #region Read DataBase File Function
    /// 

    public DBIO()
    {
        _cnStr = string.Empty;
        _cmd = null;
        _cnn = null;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _cnStr = string.Empty;
        _cmd = null;
        _cnn = null;
    }

    private string _cnStr;
    private OleDbCommand _cmd;
    private OleDbConnection _cnn;
    private OleDbDataAdapter _oda;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder _cmdbl;

    DataTable resultDt = new DataTable();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Coonection for given file 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    public bool GetConnectionToDb(string dbName)
    {
        try
        {
            _cmd = null;
            if (_cnn != null)
                _cnn.Close();
            _cnStr = GetConnectionString(dbName);

            _cnn = new OleDbConnection(_cnStr);
            _cnn.Open();

            return true;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string GetConnectionString(string dbName)
    {
        string cnnStr;
        string provider;

        provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";

        cnnStr = "Provider=" + provider + ";Data Source=" + dbName + ";";
        
        return cnnStr;
    }

    public DataTable ImportLicenseUsageDataFromDB(string dbName)
    {
        string query;
        
        try
        {
            GetConnectionToDb(dbName);
            //Retrive Data
            _oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            query = String.Format("select Department,AllottedLicense from AllottedLicense where Server = 'LUM' OR Server = 'DSLS'");
            _cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, _cnn);
            _oda.SelectCommand = _cmd;
            _oda.Fill(resultDt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in function ImportLicenseUsageDataFromDB" + ex.StackTrace);
            Logger.OutLine("Error in function ImportLicenseUsageDataFromDB" + ex.StackTrace);
            throw ex;

        }
        finally
        {
            _cmd = null;
            if (_cnn != null)
                _cnn.Close();
            //cnn = null;
        }
        return resultDt;
    }
```

Comment: The posted code “appears” to do as you describe. What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want to load access database data in datagridview depands on combox selection

Comment: i am getting not able to find server column i want output if i select LUM server it should take LUM server data from database and load in datagrid

Comment: If you are getting an error like unable to find server, then you need to double check the servers and names you are using in the connection string. I am not sure if… `Server = 'LUM' OR Server = 'DSLS' `… will work. Have you tried one at a time? If both work individually, then I would guess the problem is with the syntax of using OR in the server definitions. Possibly… `Server = LUM, DSLS`… may work however I cannot confirm this.

Comment: You should "edit" you question and add the error information you are getting. Some may not read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Make your query

```
select Server,Department,AllottedLicense from AllottedLicense where Server = 'LUM' OR Server = 'DSLS'
```

Or if you want to choose more than those two servers

```
select server,Department,AllottedLicense from AllottedLicense
```

RowFilter is a client side thing, so you have to have the Server column in the data table data in order for the DataView to be able to find it and filter on it. Setting a RowFilter does NOT alter any query done on the server, it just filters data already downloaded from the server, which is why that data needs to contain the column you want to filter on

To be honest, if you’re going to keep that code, you might as well throw the RowFilter idea away and just use a parameterized SQL query, given that you re download from the server every time you make a new DataView- the idea of RowFilter is that you download X records from the server once and then change the RowFilter to change what the client shows. More like this, pseudocode:

```
class WhateverForm: Form{
 
   public WhateverForm(){
     someDataGrid.DataSource = db.DownloadAllDataAsDatatable();
   }

   private void SomeCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     (someDataGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = $”[Server] = ‘{someCombo.SelectedItem}’”;
   }
}
```

Stash the data table you get from your query method into the grid view data source, get it out when you need and cast it to a data table , then set the RowFilter of the DefaultView (which is a DataView) of the table. When a grid is bound to a data table  actually binds to the DefauktView so setting the RowFilter on it changes the grid contents. You don’t need to use LIKE if your combo contains exact server names, which I guess it should - using like will cause eg all the Ukraine servers to show up (as well as the UK ones) if you choose UK..